# implement modulus operator as a function implementation that is overflow safe

Tags: c++

In C++, the `%` operator is a remainder operator (`a % b` produces *a* − trunc(*a*/*b*)•*b*), but I would like to implement a modulo operator (*a* − floor(*a*/*b*)•*b*) that is overflow safe.

In particular, `mod(LONG_MIN, -1)` should have defined behavior and produce 0. (With two’s complement, the C++ standard does not define `LONG_MIN % -1` because it is defined by reference to division, and `LONG_MIN / −1` overflows.)

For example, this code implements the function except it is not overflow safe:

```
long r = x % y;
if ((x ^ y) < 0 && r != 0) {
      return r + y;
}

return r;
```

Is there an efficient way to implement this in C++  without needing to special case overflow checks? Or is the only way to do this by adding a check for overflow cases at the start of the method?

Comment: `without needing to manually implement overflow` So you want to implement something without "manually" implementing it? `Is there` No, to "handle cases", you have to actually handle them, by "manually" checking for them.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Answers diverge in C and C++, as witnessed by your comment that you need to do this for types other than `long`. In C, constants for the type are hard-coded. In C++, templates can be used to automatically adapt.

Comment: To me, you should not care about the specific value `LONG_MIN`. My rationale: overflow / underflow of signed integers is undefined behavior in C++. And `LONG_MIN` is extremely close to underflow and already has special behavior (like it cannot be negated). It is extremely unlikely that your program will ever deal with that special integer, and if it does, this might indicate a bug / bad design. Better to me is to consider `LONG_MIN` value as *already undefined behavior*.

Comment: @prapin "To me, you should not care about the specific value" - agreed. That's why I am curious if there's an implementation that produces correct result for this case without caring about the value. mod(LONG_MIN, -1) should be a valid case, even if it is unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the remainder is negative, all you need is (carefully) add the quotient value `y`.

Here is a C11 solution:

```c
static inline long safe_modulus_long(long x, long y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        // division by zero: return a 0 modulus
        return 0;
    }
    if (x == LONG_MIN && y == -1) {
        // division overflow: the modulus is actually 0
        return 0;
    }
    long r = x % y;
    if (r < 0) {
        if (y > 0)
            r = y + r;
        else
            r = -(y - r);
    }
    return r;
}
```

You can support all standard integral types with other type specific functions and a generic macro:

```c
static inline long long safe_modulus_llong(long long x, long long y) {
    [...] // same implementation as above using LLONG_MIN
}

static inline int safe_modulus_int(int x, int y) {
    [...] // same implementation as above using INT_MIN
}

static inline unsigned long long safe_modulus_ullong(unsigned long long x, unsigned long long y) {
    return y ? x % y : 0;
}

static inline unsigned long safe_modulus_ulong(unsigned long x, unsigned long y) {
    return y ? x % y : 0;
}

static inline unsigned int safe_modulus_long(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    return y ? x % y : 0;
}

#define SAFE_MUDULUS(x, y)  _Generic((x) % (y),        \
    unsigned long long int: safe_modulus_ullong(x, y), \
    long long int:          safe_modulus_llong(x, y),  \
    unsigned long int:      safe_modulus_ulong(x, y),  \
    long int:               safe_modulus_long(x, y),   \
    unsigned int:           safe_modulus_uint(x, y),   \
    int:                    safe_modulus_int(x, y))
```

For C++, you can use overloading to implement `safe_modulus` for all integral types:

```c++
static inline long long safe_modulus(long long x, long long y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        // division by zero: return a 0 modulus
        return 0;
    }
    if (x == LLONG_MIN && y == -1) {
        // division overflow: the modulus is actually 0
        return 0;
    }
    long long r = x % y;
    if (r < 0) {
        if (y > 0)
            r = y + r;
        else
            r = -(y - r);
    }
    return r;
}

static inline long safe_modulus(long x, long y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        // division by zero: return a 0 modulus
        return 0;
    }
    if (x == LONG_MIN && y == -1) {
        // division overflow: the modulus is actually 0
        return 0;
    }
    long r = x % y;
    if (r < 0) {
        if (y > 0)
            r = y + r;
        else
            r = -(y - r);
    }
    return r;
}

static inline int safe_modulus(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        // division by zero: return a 0 modulus
        return 0;
    }
    if (x == INT_MIN && y == -1) {
        // division overflow: the modulus is actually 0
        return 0;
    }
    int r = x % y;
    if (r < 0) {
        if (y > 0)
            r = y + r;
        else
            r = -(y - r);
    }
    return r;
}

static inline unsigned long long safe_modulus(unsigned long long x, unsigned long long y) {
    return y ? x % y : 0;
}

static inline unsigned long safe_modulus(unsigned long x, unsigned long y) {
    return y ? x % y : 0;
}

static inline unsigned int safe_modulus(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    return y ? x % y : 0;
}
```

Comment: My issue is I need this to work for all integral types, not just longs, is there a way to do this without checking for overflow manually?

Comment: @Wirable2323: If you wanted this for all integer types, you should have specified that in the question.

Comment: @Wirable2323: I posted a simple approach for a generic solution for all integral types.

Comment: Thank you! I guess there's no implementation of this that doesn't require special casing result of a boundary overflow case.

Comment: The question is now only tagged `C++`.  In C++, you would rather use templates to implement the generic function, not the `_Generic` macro which is C11.

Comment: @Wirable2323: I could not find a simple portable expression to avoid explicit tests and type specific code, but a simpler solution might be possible.

Comment: Templates should be doable, can use std::numeric_limits with template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just add extra checks for the boundary cases:

```
long safe_mod(long x, long y)
{
    if (x == LONG_MIN && y == -1) {
        return 0;
    } else if (x > LONG_MIN && x < 0 && y == LONG_MIN) {
        return -x;
    } else {
        long r = x % y;
        if ((x ^ y) < 0 && r != 0) {
            return r + y;
        }
        return r;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without manual boundary checks?

Comment: Those are the checks Python hides behind its `%` operator. It does them every time, needed or not. C-family languages don't. Welcome to engineering-tradeoffs land. If you need them, write them. If you don't, don't.

Comment: I see, I was wondering if there was a way to avoid special casing result of a boundary overflow case, looks like there is not.

Comment: p.s. `return r + (r>>(CHAR_BIT*sizeof r - 1)&y)` is branchless and seems unlikely to be found by an optimizer.